# SSIS Send Mail Task - Hyperlink rename

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS package that sends email via `Send Mail Task` The body of the message contains the below message:

See URL https://....... for results

Can I edit the hyperlink?

The body of the message should say:

See "Embedded Link" for results!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with a lot of my answers, I prefer a script task because I think it gives you more control. The following is a starter for sending mails...

```
        using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
        {
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("your mail client"); 

            mail.From = new MailAddress("email sending from");
            mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("email where it goes"));

            mail.Subject = "subject";

            mail.ReplyToList.Add("email where replies go");
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true; //this is important for creating hyperlinks
            mail.Body = "<p>See <a href = 'www.whereever.com'>&quot;Embedded Link&quot;</a> for results!</p>"; 
            //Note html allows for either double or single quotes. I chose single because c# uses double.
            mail.Bcc.Add("bcc email");

            SmtpServer.Port = ####;

            SmtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(from, pword);


            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
          
        }
```

We send a lot of email, and I have this as a separate package where you pass parameters for ToList, CcList, BccList, Subject and body. You obviously need to adjust code to handle that with a foreach, but I am leaving it simple in this answer.

Comment: Script task gives you more options as KeithL described above, and allows more than 256 characters (I think was limit) in the to fields (fun bug to figure out sending to multiple email addresses and no clue why it was not sending).

Comment: @Brad I forgot about that. Same with database mail. The crazy part is that you could have more characters in the GUI but it truncates it at 264(I think as well). You can basically add as many mail.ToAdd() as you want in c#.

Comment: Yea the truncation is what caused my issue and took a while to track down since I didnt see any documentation on limit.